# Label `bg` does not exist

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

This is my code for my label

```
from Tkinter import Tk, BOTH, Canvas, Text,END
import Tkinter as tk
from ttk import Frame, Button, Style, Label, Entry
from tkMessageBox import *
from random import *


class Life(Frame): #is indented correctly in my code
def __init__(self, parent):
    Frame.__init__(self, parent)
    self.parent = parent
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):
    self.parent.title('MTG LIFE COUNTER')
    self.style = Style()
    self.style.theme_use('default')
    self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)

    can = Canvas(self, width=800, height=500, borderwidth=5, background='black')
    can.pack()

    can.create_rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200, fill="white", outline="white")

    self.add = Button(self, text="Add 1", command=self.rollDice)
    self.add.place(x=20, y=210)

    self.sub = Button(self, text="Subtract 1", command=self.rollDice)
    self.sub.place(x=20, y=230)

    self.diceRoll = Button(self, text="Dice!", command=self.rollDice)
    self.diceRoll.place(x=20, y=250)

    self.coin = Button(self, text="Coin", command=self.rollDice)
    self.coin.place(x=20, y=270)

    color = 'yellow'
    l = Label(self, textvariable=color)
    self.namet = Label(self, text="What's your name?", bg='black')
    self.namet.place(x=215, y=10)


    self.v = tk.StringVar()
    self.nameBox = Text(self, height=1, width=10)
    self.nameBox.place(x=215,y=30)
```

The error I get is...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".\Mtg Life Counter.py", line 64, in <module>
main()
File ".\Mtg Life Counter.py", line 60, in main
app = Life(root)
File ".\Mtg Life Counter.py", line 12, in __init__
self.initUI()
File ".\Mtg Life Counter.py", line 39, in initUI
self.namet = Label(self, text="What's your name?", bg='black')
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 757, in __init__
Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::label", kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\ttk.py", line 555, in __init__
Tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2090, in __init__
(widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

My question is how do I change the background and foreground of a label?

I tried without the `-fg` and `-bg` options the code works just fine. Tried looking for the correct syntax all say that this is it. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: show full error message. Maybe you try to use `-bg` in different line. Or maybe you created own `Label` class without `bg` argument.

Comment: Please show your imports. Are you doing this: `from ttk import *` or `from tkinter.ttk import *`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the ttk `Label` widget, and it does not support the `bg` or `ft` options. You can use `background` and `foreground` instead.

Comment: That's awesome thanks. I found that actually writing out foreground works also.

Comment: @killer If this answer is what you were looking for, then consider to accept it.

Comment: @nbro How do i do that. Sorry I am new to this site